# English dictionary on Debian/ Linux

Tags: linux, debian, dictionary, crunchbang

I'm looking for a CLI + GUI that I can use to look-up **definitions** for [English] words, much like the Dictionary app that ships with Mac OS. The term 'dictionary' is so polluted its tricky to find candidates...

An offline SQLite DB would be ideal really, imagine it's quite enormous at the same time... failing that anything that sources Wiktionary?

Answer (score 0):

Artha and Wordnet (installed by artha) fits the bill.

Artha is a GUI that will sit in tray.
Example usage:

```
$ wordnet -over aspic
```